# Three divs stacking similar to grid style

Tags: html, css

Let's just say I have three divs: DIV1, DIV2, DIV3 is this particular order.

I would like to stack them like that:

```
    (BIG|DIV1
   DIV2)|DIV3
```

I have tried with positioning and floats, unfortunately DIVs just overlaped, hide or stacked one under the another.

Any help or advice would be great.

**UPDATED**
My current code:

```
.div1
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 125px;
    width: 500px;
}

.div2
{
    position: relative; 
}

.div3
{
    clear: both;
}
```

And the result:

```
 (BIG|DIV1
DIV2)|
 DIV3
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2">(BIG <br /> DIV2)</div>
<div class="div3">DIV3</div>
```

Comment: Use a table or absolute CSS if I understand your question, do you have an example

Comment: @IanO.S, Do you you mean position: absolute?

Comment: Which div dictates height? I assume that 1 and 3 should each be half the height of 2. Is 2 50% width?

Comment: @isherwood, div2 dictates height and div2 width is 120px.

Comment: Ok. You haven't posted any HTML. Is div arrangement important?

Comment: @isherwood, div arrangement is the most important thing here. If I could change the arrangement of div, it would be easy to complete what I want, but I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution employs a relatively-positioned wrapper. I'm hoping that this is available to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLRR8/2/

```
#div1 {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
#div2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#div3 {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>

#div1{
  width:200px;
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
#div2{
  width:100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#div3{
  width:100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Good example, but what if I don't know the height (dynamic height)?

Comment: The heights could be dynamic.  I just set them in the example.

Comment: I think I posted this before there was more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you'd post what code you have tried.  If i'm understanding what  you want right, this should do it:

```
#one {
    clear: both;
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#two {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#three {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```